# Why is Torg a common example in Klingon examples on Duolingo?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, klingon-language, the-search-for-spock

I don't know if this is on-topic or not, but it has to do with *Star Trek*, so I think it is.

Anyway, I use the site Duolingo to learn a few languages. One of the recent additions, after much tinkering, is the Klingon language.

In order to help people learn, various names are used to illustrate actions and such. For example, when talking about people who admire each other, it refers to Worf and Martok, and when talking about people who hate each other, it refers to Gowron and Duras. However, I am puzzled about why the character of Torg is so frequently referenced.

For those who don't know, Torg was an officer of Kruge's ship in the film *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock*. He seems somewhat unimportant, so why is his name so frequently used on the site?

Comment: It sounds like you answered your own question - _He seems somewhat unimportant_.  Just like every Tom, Dick, Harry & Sally or Alice & Bob, maybe Torg was chosen because he was unimportant and represents your "everyday Klingon."

Comment: Mara as well. https://www.inverse.com/article/42394-klingon-tests-duolingo-star-trek-who-are-torg-and-mara

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## *Star Trek III* crystallized the modern portrayal of Klingons in the Star Trek universe and so its characters are important for that reason.

Torg may have been unimportant in general, but the film in which he appeared is significant for crystallizing the portrayal of Klingons as we know them now.  In contrast, Klingon behaviour, physical attributes, costumes, and cultural notes were quite simple in *The Original Series*.

*The Motion Picture* (1979) was crucial for introducing the modern look of Klingons with forehead ridges.  However, they only appear on screen for a few minutes with little dialogue.  It is *The Search for Spock* (1984) that revised their culture and interactions in a way that persisted throughout the *TNG* era.  This includes the further development of the language, the willingness to die for the Empire, the willingness to prove oneself in tests of mettle, and the ease with which superior officers may execute lower officers for failure.

As such, Torg's interactions with Commander Kruge help to set the tone of Klingon culture and form important examples for the human student of Klingon culture.

(See also this [question and answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105225/did-christopher-lloyd-invent-the-klingon-warrior).)

Answer (score 3):

Torg was captured by the Federation in *Star Trek III: The Search for Spock*, and the preface to Marc Okrand's book on the Klingon language, *The Klingon Dictionary
The Official Guide to Klingon Words and Phrases* (ISBN: 978-0671745592), makes it clear that that prisoner is the principle informant on which the work is based.

Comment: Maltz was taken prisoner. Torg didn't speak enough English to be concerned about a computer counting numbers down to zero. Don't be like Torg and explode - be multilingual.